# MongoLab: using php to PUT update using CURL

Tags: php, mongodb, curl, mlab

I have been trying to use MongoLabs api to simplify my life, and for the most part it was working until I tried to push updates to the db using php and curl,  anyway no dice.  My code is similar to this:

```
$data_string = json_encode('{"user.userEmail": "USER_EMAIL", "user.pass":"USER_PASS"}');
try { 
$ch = curl_init();

//need to create temp file to pass to curl to use PUT
$tempFile = fopen('php://temp/maxmemory:256000', 'w');
if (!$tempFile) {
    die('could not open temp memory data');
}
fwrite($tempFile, $data_string);
fseek($tempFile, 0); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $tempFile); // file pointer

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, DB_API_REQUEST_TIMEOUT);                                                                    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                       
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string),
    )                                                                              
);   

$cache = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    return FALSE;
}
```

My problem seems to be with MongoLab's api.  The code bit works perfect except for the fact that labs tells me that the data I am passing is an 'Invalid object{ "user.firstName" :"Pablo","user.newsletter":"true"}: fields stored in the db can't have . in them.'.  I have tried passing a file and using the postfields, but neither worked.

When I test it on firefox's Poster plugin the value work fine.  If someone out there has a better understanding of MongoLabs stuff I would love some enlightenment.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would take the error message literally.  You can't have field name with "." in them, so try user_firstName, user_pass or similar.

Comment: I understand that but in the later part I was able to test the api with the same sample and it was functioning perfectly. So as I understand it the problem is not so much data but how i am passing it to the api.  Something is different about how it is assigned to the body/content that allows it to be read as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After sometime working with some other functionality of the project I realized my mistake, and ultimately the source of the confusion.

The curl PUT was intended to send modifier operations to MongoDB.  I was sending all my data as JSON and was interrupting decoding it to use in PHP then re-encoding part of it to send back. So the orignal data received looks something like this:

```
{"userEmail":"p@g.com","pass":"****", "$oid":"5555", "$set":{"user.firstName":"Pablo","user.newsletter":"true"}}
```

The problem was that I was grabbing the value of "$set" object (in php) and reencoding only the value, `{"user.firstName":"Pablo","user.newsletter":"true"}` without the operator `"$set"` and was sending it giving the error. In this case the proper string to send would have been `{"$set":{"user.firstName":"Pablo","user.newsletter":"true"}}`

While this is a simple mistake I hope that the next time someone does something like this and gets an invalid object error that they are luck enough to find this.

Comment: I'm having the same issue - what does the final snippet look like?

Answer (score 6):

You will need to remove the dots from your field names. You might try going to a schema like this:

```
{ "user": { "userEmail": "USER_EMAIL", "pass": "USER_PASS" } }
```

Unfortunately, MongoDB doesn't support using dots in field names. This is because its query language uses the dot as an operator to chain nested field names. If MongoDB were to allow dots in field names dotted queries would become ambiguous without some kind of escaping mechanism.

If this document were legal:

```
{ "bow.ties": "uncool", "bow": { "ties": "cool" } }
```

This query would be ambiguous:

```
{ "bow.ties": "cool" }
```

Not clear if the document would match or not. Did you mean the field "bow.ties" or the field "ties" nested within the value of field "bow"?

Here's a capture of a mongo shell session demonstrating these ideas.

```
% mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.1.1
connecting to: test
> db.stuff.save({"bow.ties":"uncool"})
Wed Jul 18 11:17:59 uncaught exception: can't have . in field names [bow.ties]
> db.stuff.save({"bow":{"ties":"cool"}})
> db.stuff.find({"bow.ties":"cool"})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5006ff3f1348197bacb458f7"), "bow" : { "ties" : "cool" } }
```

Comment: Thanks, while this is an working answer for MongoDB(which I was aware of), I don't believe it is the answer to the problem I am having with the MongoLabs API. The reason for keeping this format (if possible) is that it was previously working with the app through js.  I am trying to avoid a complete rewrite if possible.

Comment: Well you win :) I will have to rewrite it.  I was talking to the guys at MongoLabs, and they have no idea how it Poster is making it work. there must be magic in the plugin. >_< This seems to be an unintended effect. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You might want to look at the documents Poster creates. If it's actually getting dots into the field names in the database then I'd call that a bug. The danger is that other features or tools (e.g. queries, mongodump, the MongoLab UI) will be unable to handle the illegal characters. However, it might actually be doing some remapping of dots to some other character.